# XMPP strophe Connection attach process failed

Tags: connection, xmpp, strophe

I'm able to create a XMPP connection on page load. However whenever I move to another pages, I want to use the same connection to remove recurring notifications in client. I've used following code.

```
$(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {
    var jid = $.jStorage.get('JID', null);
    var sid = $.jStorage.get('SID', null);
    var rid = $.jStorage.get('RID', null);
    if ((jid != null) && (sid != null) && (rid != null)) {
        var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind");
        conn.attach(jid, sid, rid, function () {
            alert('Connection attach success.');
            Gab.connection = conn;
        });
    }
    else {
        var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind");
        conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {
            if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
                $(document).trigger('connected');
            } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
                $(document).trigger('disconnected');
            }
        });
        Gab.connection = conn;
    }
});
```

And in unload:

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    if (Gab.connection != null) {
        Gab.connection.pause();
        $.jStorage.set('JID', Gab.connection.jid);
        $.jStorage.set('SID', Gab.connection.sid);
        $.jStorage.set('RID', Gab.connection.rid);
    } else {
        $.jStorage.flush();
    }
//    Gab.connection = null;
    alert('paused/disconnected');
})
```

It attaches to connection, however as soon as it attaches, it says (POST http://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind 404 Not Found 36ms) in Firebug console. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not trust unload. Instead store/update your RID on every cb from the xmpp server. Make sure your RID is getting incremented on each call as well.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to inspect the body of the message. Some XMPP servers return HTTP 404 on terminate.